# Load different background image without loading default

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, background-image

My rails project has a default pattern background for all the pages. I'm trying to set the root page with a whole-screen background image. Upon loading, this works as expected. However, when opening the page one can see a two-step delay as the page first opens the default colorful background, and then lays the image over the page. Is there a way I can not load the default background on this one view in order to avoid that two-step view during loading?

I have given my root view (static_pages#index) a #landing-page id.

CSS:

```
#landing-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(ripples.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  background: url('congruent_pentagon.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If first background comes from body, solution will be add different classes for main and other pages to body in your layout

```
<body class="<%= current_page?('/') ? 'main-page' : 'page' %>">
```

and in your css instead

```
body {
    background: url('congruent_pentagon.png');
}
```

write

```
.main-page {
    background: none;
}

.page {
    background: url('congruent_pentagon.png');
}
```